# $max operator does not seem to be working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called "snapshots" which has an index defined like this:

```
{ systemSnapshotsId: 1, dataType: 1, startFrame: -1 }
```

I'm trying to create a query using the $max operator to define an upper bound of that index for the query but it seems to have no effect.

If I perform the following query without using max I get a count of 469461 documents.

```
db.snapshots.find({systemSnapshotsId: ObjectId("---"), dataType: "blah"}).count()
```

When I add the max() operator, using the following query, I get a count of 469461 documents.

```
db.snapshots.find({systemSnapshotsId: ObjectId("---"), dataType: "blah"}).max({systemSnapshotsId: <sameId>, dataType: "blah", startFrame: 500}).count()
```

I would expect a count of 500 with the second query, or even a count of 468961 (the total count minus 500) if I had things backward.

Comment: Is there something about the provided answer that you do not understand or otherwise need more clarification on? This is how index clipping works, so that was the point of the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you do have it backwards by the way you defined the index. Quick example to explain. Say you have this collection:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035bd2f63310180151870"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035c92f63310180151871"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035cc2f63310180151872"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035cf2f63310180151873"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035d32f63310180151874"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 5 }
```

Then you define your index:

```js
db.minmax.ensureIndex({ "a": 1, "b": 1, "c": -1 })
```

Then you run this query, with results:

```js
db.minmax.find({ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": { "$lte": 3 } })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035cc2f63310180151872"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035c92f63310180151871"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035bd2f63310180151870"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1 }
```

And then try using the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/) modifier:

```js
db.minmax.find({ "a": 1, "b": 2 }).max({ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035d32f63310180151874"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035cf2f63310180151873"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 4 }
```

It's reversed, because your index is ordered with the "highest" value of "c" in the first position. So what you want is the "reverse" which is [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/min/):

```js
db.minmax.find({ "a": 1, "b": 2 }).min({ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 })

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035cc2f63310180151872"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035c92f63310180151871"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c035bd2f63310180151870"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 1 }
```

But really, try and use [**`$lte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) or [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) operators as appropriate in preference to clipping the index bounds. It's also a sure way to avoid the logic confusion over which direction the index is sorted in.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  You're correct that I had the values for "min" and "max" reversed since my index was using a descending key.  However, it looks like the count() operator only counts the items that would be returned by the query passed to find() and ignores anything passed to min or max.  Thanks!